# Conditions in prometheus to look for certain data when a label matches a value

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, metricsql

I am looking to create a query wherein It should look for interface A and B if the instance is Host1 or else it should look for interface C & D?
I was thinking something along below lines but I guess this is not right?

(ifName{ifName=~"(A|B)"} if (ifAdminStatus{instance="Host"})) default ifName{ifName=~"pether[C|D]"}

Can I please get some help here?

Comment: What is this question about? Title mentions Prometheus, but Prometheus doesn't have neither `if` nor `default` operators. If this question is specifically about victoriametrics, please identify this in your question clearly.

Comment: Additionally, it most likely will be beneficial if you include human understandable description of what your query should do.

Comment: In PromQL terms your query would look something like this: `ifName{ifName=~"A|B", instance="Host"} or ifName{ifName=~"C|D", instance!="Host"}`. You can read more about logical operators [in documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators). For more precise answer, please include example of metric `ifName` (and `ifAdminStatus` if `ifName` doesn't have labels `ifName` and `instance`)

Comment: I won't be able to use variables with this query. This is working if I had to hard code the instance name but If I have to use variables, then I have to create two variables for same thing. Basically, we have Router1 and Router2.
Router1 has Interface 7 & 8 configured to send traffic to a switch1 and Interface 9 & 10 are sending to Switch 2. whereas router2 has Interface 9 & 10 sending to Switch 1 and Interface 7 & 8 to Switch 2. Vice Versa. We have 6 Sites like this. That's why I am using Variable and not hard coding the queries

Comment: I don't see variables in your question. And I don't really see how this is related at all.